# Align congrat blocks in user profile by height

Tags: feature-request, support, design, profile-page

> [image]

It looks inconsistent. I'm asking to align blocks to the upper or lower border. Something like this:

> [image]

Comment: I downvoted because I think the issue is mostly irrelevant and because I know as a web developer how hard it is to make two blocks equal height. Therefore this would seems to be a superfluous change to me.

Comment: @MEEisJohannGambolputty... So, basically, you just said "I can't markup this correctly, so I downvoted the question". Am I right?

Comment: What is your question? Is one of the picturse supposed to be an incorrect display, and the other correct? Or are both of them wrong? If one them is wrong (or both of them are), explain why and what you propose as a fix. Don't *just* post two graphic images without any other explanation. *Especially* not if you're going to use the `feature-request` tag. It's not only impossible for people with screen readers to understand pictures, but nobody else is sure to understand what you're asking.

Comment: No I downvoted because I disagree with this being 1) worth a fix and 1) really a bug. And not because I couldn’t do it. I can do it but it would require a lot of changes that aren’t it worth under the knowledge that SE wants a full makeover of the profile page.

Comment: @JasonBassford sorry, I'm not fluent in english, but I'll try to explain it.

Comment: @MEEisJohannGambolputty... actually, with flex boxes it's 5 mins work. But thanks for the explanation, I got your point.

Comment: +1 This is a more understandable question after the edit.

Comment: @MEEisJohannGambolputty... It was never proposed as a *bug*. It was proposed as a *feature request*.

Comment: Yes I know that with flexbox the issue could be resolved easily. My point is, Stack Exchange is not using flexbox (for this part of the site) and changing the layout might take longer than what it is worth (especially as the layout will be changed in the future eventually). Re, @Jason's comment oops, didn't see it, doesn't make my argument less valid, though. *On [tag:feature-request]s downvoting means disagreement with the proposal*.

Comment: +1 Nice catch, I also think this deserves attention. If flexbox can't be used for whatever reason, it can be easily done with javascript anyway :)